# to show the weights of edges in a projected network

Tags: python, networkx

I have projected a bipartite graph and made a new weighted graph.  I would like to draw the graph, and show the edge weights.

Here is my attempt.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
g=nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'],bipartite=0)
g.add_nodes_from(['t1','t2','t3','t4'],bipartite=1)
g.add_edges_from([('s1','t1'),('s1','t4'),('s2','t1'),('s2','t2'),('s3','t1'),('s3','t4'),('s4','t3'),('s5','t2'),('s5','t3')])
l=bipartite.weighted_projected_graph(g,['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'])
nx.draw(l, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The node labels appear, but not the edge weights.  How can I show the edge weights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've modified your code to include `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels`

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
g=nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'],bipartite=0)
g.add_nodes_from(['t1','t2','t3','t4'],bipartite=1)
g.add_edges_from([('s1','t1'),('s1','t4'),('s2','t1'),('s2','t2'),('s3','t1'),('s3','t4'),('s4','t3'),('s5','t2'),('s5','t3')])
l=bipartite.weighted_projected_graph(g,['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'])
pos = nx.spring_layout(l)
nx.draw(l, pos = pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(l, pos)
```

This will probably show more than you want.  I think it's set up for cases where edges may have somewhat arbitrary attributes.  I think what you want is to do everything up to defining `pos` and then:

```
edge_weights = {(u,v,):d['weight'] for u,v,d in l.edges(data=True)}
nx.draw(l, pos = pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(l,pos,edge_labels=edge_weights)
```

Comment: Works fine to me

Answer (score 1):

I use this sentence that help me get weights:

```
l=bipartite.weighted_projected_graph(g3,movies)
```

input: `l.edges(data=True)`
output:`[('The Dark Knight', 'The Matrix', {'weight': 1}),
 ('The Dark Knight', 'The Shawshank Redemption', {'weight': 1}),
 ('The Social Network', 'The Matrix', {'weight': 1})]`